# Angular: How to refresh a part of html ( form / div / table )

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I have a page for create operation. In my page I have 1 form with 2 field. If I reload the page (or `window.reload` by code) I can see updates in that form. But I want to trigger a refresh on the form by pressing button click.

So please help me to write a function that can refresh the form (or any other html element like tabe/paragraph/etc.)

**.html of my form:**

```
<form class="was-validated" #zoneForm=ngForm id=#zoneForm>
  <div class=container>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-5">
        <div class="card" style="width: 35rem;">
          <div class="card-header">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-11">
                Zone Entry
              </div>
              <div class="col-1">
                <i style="margin-left: -1rem;" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="card-body">

            <div class="row mb-1">
              <div class="col-12">

                <input [(ngModel)]="code" name="code" type="number" class="custom_form_control custom input" placeholder="ID" style="padding: 0px;"
                  disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-1">
              <div class="col-12">

                <input [(ngModel)]="zonename" name="zonename" type="text" class="custom_form_control custom-input" placeholder="Zone Name" required>
                <i class="fa fa-user" style="margin-left: -1rem;font-size: 1rem; color:black;margin-top: 0.25rem;"></i>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row ">
              <div class="col-12 ">
                <button type="button " class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="margin-left: 90%; " (click)="createZone()">Save</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>



          <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</form>
```

the function should be called by clicking **Save** button

Comment: You want ChangeDetectorRef. detectChanges method

Comment: @JohnPeters can you show me a link with simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ngOnChanges()`

**Example:component.ts** file

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "child-component",
  templateUrl: "./child-component.html"
})
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() someHtml: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges() {
  ///** WILL TRIGGER WHEN PARENT COMPONENT UPDATES '**

   console.log(this.someHtml);
  }   
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use ReactiveFormModule, because it is so powerful and It is the best way to work with Forms in Angular:

form example:

component.ts

```
public myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      one: [],
      two: []
    })
  }

  submit() {
    this.myForm.reset()
  }
```

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <input formControlName="one" type="text"/>
  <input formControlName="two" type="text"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

I recommend you to look Angular Reactive Form docs:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Look this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zevbtg?file=src/app/app.component.html

You should keep in mind that ngModel will be deprecated to work with forms on next versions...

Answer (score 0):

please use **ngOnInit()** in your method without refresh page.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-component",
 templateUrl: "./my-component.html"
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() someHtml: string;

  constructor() {}

ngOnInit(){}    

createZone(){
this.ngOnInit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit(){
this.myForm = fb.group({
      one: [],
      two: []
    })
}

  submit() {
  this.http.post().subscribe(
  (data) => {
  this.ngOnInit();
  console.log(data);
  this.myForm.reset()
})
   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A scenario I had, where I needed to update an HTML structure that used a boolean to show part of the page before calling a method for printing.

```
<div id="div">
  <component [showLast]="isPrint"></component>
</div>

print() {
  const selectionHtml: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('div');
  this.isPrint = true; //Boolean I used to change the component inside the div
  selectionHtml.onload
  setTimeout(() => {
    PrintUtil.print('page');
    this.isPrint = false;
    selectionHtml.onload;
  }, 100);
}
```